# What is the recommended way to get screen dimension on android

Tags: android, android-layout, screen, dimensions, android-screen

Having done some research, I come up with the following three methods for getting screen size of an android device. But it's still not clear to me which one to use in which condition. Are they all equivalent? is one faster than the other? What's the difference? Are they Api level specific? Which one should I use? I am looking for an easy to digest, authoritative answer that addresses all concerns. I have already read a lot. So it would be helpful if I don't have to look through a bunch of comments to try to come up with a summary of what is the authoritative truth.

```
public static Point getDimension(Activity context) {
    Display display = context.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay();
    Point size = new Point();
    display.getSize(size);
    return size;
}

public static Point getDimension(Context c) {
    Resources r = c == null ? Resources.getSystem() : c.getResources();
    DisplayMetrics metrics = r.getDisplayMetrics();
    return new Point(metrics.heightPixels, metrics.widthPixels);
}

public static Point getScreenSize(Activity activity) {
    final DisplayMetrics displayMetrics = new DisplayMetrics();
    activity.getWindowManager().getDefaultDisplay().getMetrics(displayMetrics);
    return new Point(displayMetrics.heightPixels, displayMetrics.widthPixels);
}
```

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski do you overhear yourself? So to ask a question, a person must be an expert? How many people know how to do what you are asking this person to go do? And among those who may claim to know, how many can do it effectively?

Comment: No, one do not need to be a expert. One should put some effort to solve the problem by himself, and ask when s/he really hit the wall. Starting from posting question here is pure laziness

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski for someone eager to downvote, your argument does not follow from the evidence. The OP presents three methods, which were synthesized from research. So, no, I didn't start with this post. Get over yourself.

Answer (score 1):

They are essentially the same.
`Display.getSize()` is only available from API 13 (honeycomb)

the first parameter of a `Point` is x, which is the horizontal axis, the second is y which should be vertical - as such you should switch the order you pass `heightPixels` and `widthPixels` into the Point constructor.

You could also reuse a `Point` field member rather than allocating a new one each time. If the activity isn't handling its own configuration changes, you can read the dimensions once and store the results - since the dimensions won't change without the activity being restarted.

Comment: So it's sounding like I should combine the three methods into one and use if clauses to check for api levels. Is that an accurate revision? Also, thanks for the `Point` tip: +1.